# Did Newton discuss and/or use the principle of moments?

Tags: physics, theoretical-physics, newton, archimedes

This question comes from a point of view of a student in current times. The general curriculum for a physics student presents that a static analysis of a simple system requires that the forces in each direction sum to zero (i.e. the object does not move). The explanation that comes generally is that this is simple implementation of Newton's first law. However, it is often times, when considering truss systems for example, that Newton's first law is not sufficient to provide enough equations and we must supplement the law of moments: around every point within a non-rotating object, the sum of moments should be equal to zero.

I understand that this was essentially known by Archimedes (and I wonder, why don't we call it Archimedes' law?). However, this does not get the same reputation, in my eyes, as Newton's first law (which seems a foundation of modern physics).

I was wondering whether the principle of moments, as a tool in engineering and in mathematics, was known as a "law" (equivalent and on the same standing as we regard Newton's laws)?

Comment: I believe it was Euler who formalized the study of Rigid Body Mechanics some ~100 years after Newton, this paper outlines some of the history http://www.vti.mod.gov.rs/ntp/rad2007/3-07/hedr/hedr.pdf .

Comment: Newton's first law as such applies to material points. *Both* principles of zero resultant force and zero resultant moment as equilibrium conditions for systems of points or extended rigid bodies are derivative "implementations" of it, and so neither has the same status of a fundamental law. Similarly, from the second law for points one can derive for systems of points both translational second law with forces and rotational second law with torques. The former has the same form as for points, but it is not fundamental either.